# Changing Salesforce system language from Apex class/controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, language

Is it possible to change the current system language (Language Settings) from an Apex code? We are creating a configuration menu on a vf page where the user can change the current default system language.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the apex:page [language](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm#d711936e74) attribute to alter the translations on a per page basis (via Neeraj's comment).

**language**

> The language used to display labels that have associated translations in Salesforce. This value overrides the language of the user viewing the page. Possible values for this attribute include any language keys for languages supported by Salesforce, for example, "en" or "en-US".

---

I suspect you want to change the [Organization](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm)

**LanguageLocaleKey**

> The same as Language, the two-to-five character code which represents the language and locale ISO code. This controls the language for labels displayed in an application.

and/or

**DefaultLocaleSidKey**

> Default locale SID key.

fields.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that the LanguageLocaleKey is usually used when writing test class i.e. inserting new user in a test class. What I am looking for is some language setting that they can change on their vf page so all the labels/fields on the vf page are translated to that language. (Not sure if I am explaining my question correctly).

Comment: I suspect you will need to change the `User.LanguageLocaleKey` to alter the label translations that are applied to the Visualforce page.

Comment: You can only change the User language, not just the language used to display one specific VF page

Comment: I came up with this solution:                                    User currentUserInfo = [select LanguageLocaleKey from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
currentUserInfo.LanguageLocaleKey = 'pt_BR';
update currentUserInfo;                                               But it changes the language for all the users who are viewing the vf page. I need to change the language to a per-user basis.

Comment: @Neeraj Your sample code seems reasonable. Seems like it would change the language for any user how visits the page and cause that Apex to execute. I don't see how it would affect users other than the current one.

Comment: The problem with my solution above is the language changed by one user is reflected for all the users working/interacting with that org. For example if I am in Houston and change the language to Spanish for user A, someone in Dallas interacting with user A profile will start seeing everything in spanish, even the public facing vf pages and labels. The other solution that I found (cannot believe it was right there) is to use the apex page attribute "language" and set the language in the vf pages itself without touching the user/system language.